# How to automatically choose between beautifulsoup or selenium based on Static or Dynamic generated elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Is there any way to use as an anchor to separate Content Type in scraping procedure to classify each content automatically ?
I want to check by bs4 at the first and if it wasn't success, try with selenium to classify website scraper type to below classes:
1- beautifulsoup
2- selenium

Example of static rendered websites:

[Static rendered example 1](https://www.needmode.com/product/python-3-tutorial/)

[Static rendered example 2](https://www.daneshgah.ac/courses/%d8%a2%d9%85%d9%88%d8%b2%d8%b4-%d8%a8%d8%b1%d9%86%d8%a7%d9%85%d9%87-%d9%86%d9%88%db%8c%d8%b3%db%8c-%d9%be%d8%a7%db%8c%d8%aa%d9%88%d9%86-3-%d9%be%db%8c%d8%b4%d8%b1%d9%81%d8%aa%d9%87-%d8%af%d9%88%d8%b1/)

example of dynamic rendered websites:
[Dynamic rendered example 1](https://www.digikala.com/main/electronic-devices/)

As you know that, beautifulsoup is not able to scrape some websites (Dynamic rendered example 1) and in this situation we need to choose selenium as scraper, but selenium is not fast enough and my prefer is use bs4 at the first and if it wasn't success to scrape, I use selenium in second order.

Static rendered websites is okay, but the problem is with dynamic rendered websites, Can you suggest me a peace of code to do that ?

I tested on selenium and bs4 separately and it's worked but I don't know how to detect scraper type automatically based on content type.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a relibale way to do what you want, I'd say there's 2 types of dynamically rendered content.

- A regular webpage that loads content via JS requests to an API
- A Website wholly built with a JS framework like Vue, React, Angular, etc...

You could check for error messaged from each framework like "This website needs JS to work....." but that's not reliable. If you start with BS4 you should verify how the content is loaded beforehand to code the requests with `requests` or `urllib` or whatever and at that point you might as well classify the website between static or dynamic yourself.

What I think you should do is use always `selenium`, if solution A works 60% of the time and solution B works 100% of the time, why bother with solution A?

Comment: So selenium working on All website types ? At least is this able to do everything that BS4 did for me ?

Comment: Selenium simulates a browser and runs JS so it should work just like a browser, as for doing things BS4 does, it does not, but you can request a page with selenium, grab the source code once it's loaded everything, JS and dynamic content included, then pass that html to BS4 and search tags and whatever you do with BS4.

Comment: Amazing, seems to be good to make a combination between selenium and bs4 to use both functions.

Comment: Really BS4 does not make any HTTP requests so I assume you're using `requests` and `selenium`, and `selenium` is just `requests` with JS. So BS4 should always be there for easy HTML parsing, regardless of how you obtain that HTML.

Comment: There is no html or js element or something to test with bs4 and if it fails go to use selenium after that?

Comment: No need for that.

Comment: Can I add selenium to my project that's works with bs4 before and get all dynamic rendered elements completly to feed into bs4 right?

It was my first bs4 request

**```  html = request.urlopen(urlSource[1]).read().decode('utf8')
  # html parsing
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")```**

Now I must add selenium webdriver before and remove request.urlopen and use selenium webdriver to get html parts?

Comment: Yes, you could use something like `driver.get(URL)` and then `html = driver.page_source`